# Spectrum of magnetic Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Consider the discrete magnetic Laplacian on $\mathbb Z^2.$

$$(\Delta_{\alpha,\lambda}\psi)(n_1,n_2) = e^{-i \pi \alpha n_2} \psi(n_1+1,n_2) + e^{i\pi \alpha n_2} \psi(n_1-1,n_2) +  \lambda \left(e^{i \pi \alpha n_1} \psi(n_1,n_2+1)+e^{-i\pi \alpha n_1} \psi(n_1,n_2-1) \right)$$

We consider $\alpha$ irrational.
It is known (to me) that the spectrum of this operator as a set always coincides with the spectrum of the Almost Mathieu operator and that this operator has no point spectrum. But I am curious whether it is known when the spectrum (depending on $\lambda$) of this operator is absolutely continuous/singular continuous. Apparently, it is singular continuous if $\lambda =1$ as the measure of the spectrum is zero in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[Metal-insulator transition for the almost Mathieu operator](http://emis.ams.org/journals/Annals/150_3/jitomirs.pdf) (1999) proves that the spectrum is purely absolutely continuous for $\lambda<1$. (They write $\lambda<2$, but their $\lambda$ is different by a factor of two.) The spectrum is singular-continuous if $\lambda>1$ and $\alpha$ is a [Liouville number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) For a more extensive discussion, see the article by Y. Last (page 102 and following) in [Sturm-Liouville theory.](http://dl.iranidata.com/book/daneshgahi/sturm.liouville.theory.Past.and.Present(www.IraniData.com).pdf#page=116)

Comment: These references are about one-dimensional operators  and have little to do with the OP's question, which is about a two-dimensional operator.

Comment: @ChristianRemling --- correct me if I'm wrong, please, but the papers I referred to address the Almost Mathieu operator on $\mathbb{Z}$ (one-dimensional), which is equivalent to the discrete magnetic Laplacian on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (two-dimensional). See for example eqs. 1.1 and 1.2 from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02101702). This is why the Mathieu eq. is used to study the spectrum of electrons in a two-dimensional lattice in a perpendicular magnetic field (Hofstadter problem). The parameter $\alpha$ in the Mathieu operator is the magnetic flux through a unit cell.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this, this is relevant. However, my original comment still seems correct because the correspondence between the two problems (apparently) is not very strong: it just concerns the spectrum as a set and the DOS; the papers you quote prove much more refined results on the type of the spectrum of Almost Mathieu, which will not give anything on the 2d problem.